# Differences between 2 pointers of a template

Tags: c++

I want to know if there is any difference between 2 pointers (as data members) in a template class. For example:

```
template <typename E>
class Link
{
private:
    E element;
    Link* a;
    Link<E>* b;
};
```

Is "a" analogous to "b", I wonder?

Comment: Yes, both are analogous.

Answer (score 14):

Both forms are valid. When the name of a class template is used inside the class template scope without template arguments, it resolves to the name of the "current" template specialization.

`a` and `b` have the same type.

It's the same rule that makes it possible for us to write for example:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(Foo const&) = default;
```

... instead of the more verbose:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo(Foo<T> const&) = default;
```

Comment: Isn't `Foo<T>::Foo<T>(Whatever)` ill-formed?

Comment: @PasserBy - Well, maybe not quite as verbose as I thought :)